# Group by on a List And Return Top 1 Row

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a list acd with key value pair.

```
  var acd = zebra.Where(v => v.Key.StartsWith("alpha"));
```

KEY, VALUE

1. alphaABC, TOP323
2. alphaBCD, BIG456
3. alphaDEF, TOP323

What i would want is to get only One Key (Any) from multiple keys which have same values.
In this case 1 and 3 have same values.

I would like to get a new list like below:

1. alphaABC, TOP323
2. alphaBCD, BIG456

Basically unique Values only. Any Help ?

Comment: You can always use a `HashSet<T>` as a helping data structure, iterate your collection and try adding every key to HashSet, which allows only one instance of each `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = zebra
 .Where(v => v.Key.StartsWith("alpha"))
 .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
 .Select(group => group.First())
 .ToArray();

 foreach(var item in items)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() 
{ new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ABC", "TOP323"), 
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BCD", "BIG456"), 
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DEF", "TOP323") };

        var result = (from d in data
                     group d by d.Value
                     into g
                     select new
                                {
                                    row = g.FirstOrDefault()
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Or with more lambda goodness:  var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>(zebra.Count);
foreach (KeyValuePair pair in zebra) {
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(pair.Value)) {
        dict.Add(pair.Value, pair.Key);
    }
}
```

Note that we invert the meaning of key and value here. We use `pair.Value` as key in the `dict`, since we want unique values.

As an alternative you could also declare the dictionary as `Dictionary<string,KeyValuePair<string,string>>` and add like this

```
dict.Add(pair.Value, pair);
```